# /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf versus /etc/httpd/conf.d/owncloud.http /Directory directives

Tags: apache

Below is a segment from the owncloud.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d. It is the intent to lock out all access except the 10.0 intranet and a limited set of external ip address xx.yy.0.0. However the configuration is not locking out other access. All external address are being allowed. Is there something obvious with this configuration.

```
<Directory /var/www/http/owncloud/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 10.0.0.0/16
     Allow from xx.yy.0.0/16
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's either being overridden in a different configuration section (like Location or LocationMatch) or your clients are coming through proxies that make them appear to match your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
     Deny from none
How ever swap around your ip config and change it to deny
     Allow from 10.0.0.0/16
     Allow from xx.yy.0.0/16